# Retrieving city info (Hotels, Restaurants, Attractions etc.)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making an app that records a destination (a city, state, country, town, suburb etc.) Using **just** this information, how could I retrieve information about the top-rated business which include:

- Shopping Malls
- Restaurants
- Attractions
- Hotels
- Shops (Bookstores, CD shops, etc.)

And their prices (if so), reviews, and possibly even photos? I am not an expert in this field, more of an intermediate programmer so I know this will be more than tough... So is there an API (if so a simple one) that would provide information? Are there any tutorials or sample code as a base template or example I can dive into? Is this a very ambitious and hard task?

What I am really looking for is online tutorials or sample code, because usually these tutorials provided are quite vague. So please try not to answer with: "Use yelp"

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using Yelp's API. http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started

Comment: Thanks! Are there any tutorials on this? Or example code (except for the official) like on github?

Comment: @RohanKapur They have examples on that page which should be able to point you in the right direction and get you started.

Comment: Thanks... I tried to signup... I live in a different country than US (Singapore).... and it says my ZIP code is invalid (which is postal code in Singapore btw)